# Head line alignment of top row in a long table

Tags: captions, longtable

I am unable to set alignment (right aligned) of the top row of long table.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{babel}


\begin{document}

Text (journal), an academic journal of language, discourse, and communication studies
Text (literary theory), any object that can be "read", including literature and other objects
Textbook, a manual of instruction in any branch of study
Religious text, writings which various religious traditions consider to be sacred
Written text, communication that represents language through the inscription of signs and symbols

\setstretch{.5}

\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{135pt}>{\raggedright}p{135pt}r}

\caption{Why Thousand USD is not right aligned?}

\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{\scriptsize{}(Thousand USD)}}\tabularnewline

\textbf{Country} & \textbf{District} & \textbf{Amount }\textbf{\scriptsize ('000'USD)}\tabularnewline

\hline 
\endhead
Afghanistan & L & 6\tabularnewline
\hline 

Australia & K & 2,9\tabularnewline
\hline 

Austria & I & 3\tabularnewline
\hline 

Bahrain & K & 3\tabularnewline
 & L & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 

Belgium & K & 1\tabularnewline
 & L & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 

Canada & I & 99,965\tabularnewline
 & K & 9\tabularnewline
 & L & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 

Cayman I & I & 2\tabularnewline
 & Ka & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 

\textbf{Grand Total} &  & \textbf{2}\tabularnewline
\hline 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This presumably generated _errors_ (the pdf is essentially arbitrary after an error, you should ask why there is an error not why the pdf looks the way it does)

Answer (score 3):

With

```
\caption{Why Thousand USD is not right alligned?}\\
```

I have no problem. The `\\` is important.